# what will happen if I exceed the rate of write operations for an individual collection more than 1,000 operations/second?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

currently I want to make notifications system, I have root collection called `notifications` and inside each notification document I will have `receivers` subcollection

I will write some userIDs inside `receivers` subcollection using batch operation like this in my callable cloud function

```
    let batch = db.batch()

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach( snapshot => {

        const data = snapshot.data()
        const userID = data.userID

        let notificationReceiverRef = db.doc(`notifications/${notificationID}/receivers/${ID}`)
        batch.set(notificationReceiverRef, {
            userID: userID,
            createdAt: now
        })


    })


    await batch.commit()
```

but I just read some limitations in firestore in [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices), it is said that I should keep  the rate of write operations for an individual collection under 1,000 operations/second.

in my app, there is possibility that I will write around 10.000 - 50.000 documents inside `receivers` subcollection, to keep the record who receives the notification.

but I don't know, if I will exceed that 1,000 operations/second or not if using batch operation like the code I write above. will cloud function automatically manage this ? if not, what will happen if I exceed this limit ?

I have no other idea how to a keep lot of records but also comply to the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exceed any of the write limits, the write will simply fail.  You should check for errors and retry if that happens.

You're going to have to think carefully about how you actually retry.  It will almost certainly not be automatically managed for you the way you want.  You can configure a Cloud Function to enable retries, but that only works for background function driven by an event, and it will retry the entire event.  HTTP triggers do not have a retry configuration - those will have to be retried from the client.

Comment: if I have `users` as the root collection, inside each user document It has `inbox` subcollection, then If I write 10.000 documents to 10.000 different user `inbox` subcollection. will I hit that 1000 write operation/second limit because it is in the same root `users` collection ?

Comment: No, subcollections are not related to parent collections except by path name only.  Each have their own indexes that are different.